# Why does initTESTING() with type - (id) from an Objective-C class fail invoking in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have an

@interface Apple :

```
- (id) initTESTING()
```

but in my Swift file, I am not allowed to do:

```
Apple().initTESTING()
```

or...

```
Apple.initTESTING()
```

I have the .h properly including in the bridging header.

Comment: The problem is probably the `init` name, which is reserved for initializers.

Comment: @matt submit that comment for the win!

Comment: You mean I was right???? Wow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing it's the `init...` name. Swift probably reserves such names for initializers; after all, it has to have *some* sort of internal rule about what methods are initializers, which take special syntax and are specially treated. Thus there is no way Swift can call a method named in this way as an ordinary instance method.

Comment: Of course, even before Swift it was never a good idea to name a non-initializer in this way, because ARC was mismanaging the memory for it even in Objective-C. ARC, too, relies on naming conventions...